# Improve Laravel Eloquent Query

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have this relation in my model...

```
$this->hasMany('App\Inventory')->where('status',1)
            ->whereNull('deleted_at')
            ->where(function($query){
                $query
                    ->where('count', '>=', 1)
                    ->orWhere(function($aQuery){
                        $aQuery
                            ->where('count', '=' , 0)
                            ->whereHas('containers', function($bQuery){
                                $bQuery->whereIn('status', [0,1]);
                            });
                    });
            })
            ->orderBy('updated_at','desc')
            ->with('address', 'cabin');
```

And Sql query generated are :

```
select
  *
from
  `inventories`
where
  `inventories`.`user_id` = 17
  and `inventories`.`user_id` is not null
  and `status` = 1
  and `deleted_at` is null
  and (
    `count` >= 1
    or (
      `count` = 0
      and exists (
        select
          *
        from
          `containers`
        where
          `inventories`.`id` = `containers`.`inventory_id`
          and `status` in (0, 1)
      )
    )
  )
  and `inventories`.`deleted_at` is null
order by
  `updated_at` desc
limit
  10 offset 0
```

Unfortunately this take more than 2sec in MySql,

There are anyways to improve and reduce the query time for this?!

Each inventory has many containers. when inventory count is 0 (0 mean out of stock but sometimes there are disabled containers that mean inventory is not out of stock yet.) the real count is depend on count of containers with status [0,1] (containers have other statuses...).

I have an idea to have a column on inventory to count containers with [0,1] status, and update it in other processes to improve this query. but this take too much time and need to modify other process.

Inventories `show create table`

```
CREATE TABLE `inventories` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cabin_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `address_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `count` mediumint NOT NULL,
  `status` mediumint NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `available_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=37837 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Containers `show create table`

```
CREATE TABLE `containers` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `inventory_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `order_id` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=64503 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

---

Used Solution due comments (Thanks to [@ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth) [@vixducis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/433714/vixducis) [@Breezer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/260640/breezer) ):

Changed Containers engine from `MyISAM` to `InnoDB` ,

Added `INDEX` to `containers.inventory_id`

And optimize code like below and limit `whereHas` select query

```
$this->hasMany('App\Inventory')->where('status',1)
            ->whereNull('deleted_at')
            ->where(function($query){
                $query
                    ->where('count', '>=', 1)
                    ->orWhere('count', '=' , 0)
                    ->whereHas('containers', function ($bQuery) {
                        $bQuery
                            ->select('inventory_id')
                            ->whereIn('status', [0, 1]);
                    });

            })
            ->orderBy('updated_at','desc')
            ->with('address', 'cabin');
```

for whereHas we can use `whereIn` and subQuery like below

```
->whereIn('id', function ($subQuery) {
    $subQuery->select('inventory_id')
         ->from('containers')
         ->whereIn('status', [0, 1]);
});
```

and for limiting select of `dosentHave`

```
->doesntHave('requests', 'and', function($query){
    $query->select('inventory_id');
})
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show output (as text, not images) of `show create table inventories;` and `explain select ...rest of your select`

Comment: Have you tried it before without whereHas statement? how much time it take?

Comment: your images do not contain the helpful information that show create table does.  any question to improve performance of a query needs to include show create table output for all tables in the query as well as explain output.  this output is very easy to obtain in the command line client.

Comment: @AndreHaykal without whereHas it take 30ms.

Comment: @ysth yep, i used phpmyadmin before, but i can't copy or show full query, so this time i used MySql Workbench, and updated.

Comment: I don't see explain output?

Comment: Is there any reason the `containers` table is still running on myISAM? On new-ish MySQL versions, innoDB should be outperforming myISAM. Also, defining an index on `containers.inventory_id` should help as well.

Comment: @vixducis Can you submit an answer to select?! there are no reason using myISAM, i changed to InnoDB and query get 10x faster, and with adding index it get 400x~500x faster. finally from 500ms to 1~2 ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `containers` table is still running on the MyISAM engine. While that engine is not deprecated, the development focus has shifted heavily towards InnoDB, and it should be a lot more performant. Switching to InnoDB is a good first step.

Secondly, I see that there is no index on `containers.inventory_id`. When experiencing performance issues when relating two tables, it's often a good idea to check whether adding an index on the column that relates the tables improves performance.

These two steps should make your query a lot faster.

Comment: thanks. changed Containers table to InnoDB engine and query get 10x faster, and with adding index, Query get 400x~500x faster. finally from 500ms to 1~2 ms with 100k Data.

Answer (score 0):

when your data is big, whereHas statement sometimes run slowly because it use `exists` syntax. For more detailed explanation, you can read from this [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46785552/poor-wherehas-performance-in-laravel)

To solve this, I prefer you to use [mpyw/eloquent-has-by-non-dependent-subquery](https://github.com/mpyw/eloquent-has-by-non-dependent-subquery) because it will use `in` syntax which will improve the performance. I already used this package on my project, and no problem until now.

Comment: Thanks, yes you are true, because whereHas uses (select * from) in query, and we must limit that select to column we need in relation, like i used ->whereHas('containers', function ($bQuery) {
                        $bQuery
                            ->select('inventory_id')
                            ->whereIn('status', [0, 1]);
                    });
  in this will use (select `inventory_id` from ...), and also for dosentHave again we must limit like this ->doesntHave('requests', 'and',function($bQuery){
                $bQuery->select('inventory_id');
            })

Answer (score 0):

- Change to InnoDB.
- `inventories` needs this composite index:  `INDEX(user_id, status, deleted_at, updated_at)`
- `containers` needs this composite index, not simply `(inventory_id)`, but `(inventory_id, status)`.
- Redundant:  `inventories.user_id is not null` because the test for 17 requires `NOT NULL`.
- Redundant: `deleted_at is null` simply because it is in the query twice.