# Can WhereHas Preformance be better

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Hello I have a Table With millions of records and I'm Trying To Get Model Data By Relation but it's too slow using where has

My Code V1

```
$influencers = Brand::query()->with('campaignBrandInfluencers.influencer', 'campaignBrandInfluencers.campaign')->whereHas('campaignBrandInfluencers', function ($q) {
            $q->whereIn('status', [CampaignCases::VISIT, CampaignCases::CONFIRMATION, CampaignCases::COVERAGE]);
            $q->whereHas('influencer', function ($q) {
                $q->whereNull('deleted_at');
            });
            $q->whereHas('campaign', function ($q) {
                $q->where('status', 1);
            });
        })->coverageFilter($filter)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

i have Tried To make it in 2 steps

```
 return $campaignInfluencers = CampaignInfluencer::query()->whereIn('status', [CampaignCases::VISIT, CampaignCases::CONFIRMATION, CampaignCases::COVERAGE])
            ->whereNotNull('brand_id')->where('brand_id', '>', 0)
            ->with('influencer', 'campaign')
             ->whereHas('influencer', function ($q) {
                $q->whereNull('deleted_at');
            })
            ->whereHas('campaign', function ($q) {
                $q->where('status', 1);
            })
            ->distinct() // Use distinct to select unique brand_id values
            ->pluck('brand_id') // Group by brand_id
            ->toArray();


 $influencers = Brand::query()->with('campaignBrandInfluencers.influencer', 'campaignBrandInfluencers.campaign')->whereIn('id',$campaignInfluencers)->coverageFilter($filter)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

it takes about 40seconds to a minute so I can retrieve data

and yes I have added an index in columns I search by it

any idea How To Make it batter?

Comment: I would probably write a Raw SQL query to get just the brand ID's, then use the ID's to fetch the models you want.  ORM's aren't particularly good at optimizing queries on large datasets.  Avoid sorting and OR,  it's better to use an Union then an OR, if you want better performance.

Comment: Is your table indexed on the fields you are using for whereHas?

Comment: Oh i see you have indexed them indeed, you might want to try raw query. Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46785552/poor-wherehas-performance-in-laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the query builder instead of the eloquent orm. See the laravel docs under database -> query builder